# Last span in div changes it's width

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

So i have one div with 7 spans - each describing date. Last span behaves weirdly, it has different width, it in some ways wrap, but it has free space :/.
[Here is pic of how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eIGTD.png)

```css
.mc-dates-bar
{
    margin-left: 60px;
    width: 800px;
    height: 30px;
}

.mc-single-date
{
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: $denim;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
 <div className="mc-dates-bar">
                <span className="mc-single-date">{moment(dates[0]).format("D MMM")}</span>
                <span className="mc-single-date">{moment(dates[1]).format("D MMM")}</span>
                <span className="mc-single-date">{moment(dates[2]).format("D MMM")}</span>
                <span className="mc-single-date">{moment(dates[3]).format("D MMM")}</span>
                <span className="mc-single-date">{moment(dates[4]).format("D MMM")}</span>
                <span className="mc-single-date">{moment(dates[5]).format("D MMM")}</span>
                <span className="mc-single-date">{moment(dates[6]).format("D MMM")}</span>
            </div>
```

Comment: try to use `width` in `%` instead of fixed `800px`, may be it can solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

You've set the width of the `div` to `800px` and it looks like your `span` tags are occupying more space than this, and therefore causing the last span to wrap onto another 'line' so to speak. Try changing the property to `min-width` if that's what you're looking for, or give the `span` tags a `width: calc(100% / 7)` tag

Answer (score 0):

either remove the height of the container element `.mc-dates-bar` so it can extend in height or make the `font-size` of `.mc-single-date` smaller so they can fit or 
make the container `.mc-dates-bar` more than 800px

you are trying to fit lot of element in a small container, not possible

Answer (score 0):

If you want to place parent `div` element to center and all your child `span` elements (7 in this example) fit to `div` with equal widths your css code will likely look like this.

```
div.parentDiv {
    position:relative;
    margin:0 auto; 
    /*height: 30px;*/
    min-width:700px;
    max-width:90%;
}
span.childSpan {
    float:left;
    width:calc(100%/7);
    box-sizing:border-box; 
    text-align: center;
    /*font-weight: bold;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: $denim;
    font-size: 18px;*/
}
```

There is no need for `margin-left` in this case.
After typing this css code, every single `span` element you add with the same class will sit on `div` elegantly.

Answer (score 0):

Add `no-wrap` to your span.
Such as https://codesandbox.io/s/1rzongZL3 .

```
.mc-single-date
{
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: $denim;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-left: 15px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```